# Trying to calculate matches in a tournament using combinations, in games that have multiple players

Tags: permutations, matching-theory

I am trying to calculate opponents in matches for my app game.

In it I will have a league of a varied number (between 5-14) of players and I want to know, given the number of players in a league, what's the smallest number of games each person can play so they've played all other people in the league and equal number of times. I could obviously play out every combination, but I want to play less games if possible. Each match will have either 3 or 4 players in it (including yourself)

Some examples to help better explain...

I know that in a 9 player league, if each match has 3 opponents only, then each player can play only 8 games, resulting in playing each opponent twice. This is fewer than the full 84 possible combinations.

In an 8 player league with 4 people then it only needs 7 games per person playing each opponent 3 times.

I **THINK** I have worked out the maths on how to do get the number of matches and number of times to play each opponent, but I can't work out how to come up with the combinations of players in order to satisfy this.

I can add the maths I've worked out, but it would be quite long so I'll only do that if people need it. As that's not actually the bit I need solving. (though it's part of the solution)

I've tried both on pen and paper, and writing a program to do it. The program has had the most success, working on a variety of combinations of league and match size, but it doesn't work on all of them.

I'm at a loss right now, and looking for any sort of help.

Comment: When you say each match will have $3$ or $4$ do you mean that either all matches will have $3$ players or all matches will have $4$ players, or is it possible that some matches have $3$ players and others have $4$?

Comment: both, but they're not related. I'd like the fixtures/match opponents for all matches with 3. And then calculate it all again with 4.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about [balanced incomplete block designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design#Pairwise_balanced_uniform_designs_(2-designs_or_BIBDs)), at least if you want to enforce the rule that each player plays the same number of games.  I don't think there's a complete theory, but quite a lot of special cases are known.

Comment: @saulspatz YES! this looks like the right sort of thing. Especially the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design#Examples example (8,4,3). That is basically what I want, with two inputs of 8 and 4, and it to tell me that 3 is the smallest number. However I'm nowhere near clever enough to understand the maths on this page to work out how they got there. :(

Answer (score 0):

Organize it in some way and then look for a systematic method.

Nine players with three in each game:

```
1:2:3 1:4:5 1:6:7 1:8:9
2:4:6 2:5:8 2:7:9
3:4:9 3:5:7 3:6:8
4:7:8
5:6:9
```

Comment: @S Spring Sorry, I've got the solution for 9 with 3 players. I meant 3 opponents so you PLUS 3, i.e. 4 opponents :D

Answer (score 0):

After @Saulspatz told me what to look for, (BIBD) I found a library in the R language that worked it out for me.

https://rdrr.io/cran/crossdes/man/find.BIB.html

@Saulspatz if you want to mark up a quick answer talking about balanced incomplete block designs I'll give you a tick